# How do I stop this loop in Mars Rover Kata?

Tags: javascript, return, break

In this loop, I'm trying to stop the loop from running once I meet a certain condition such as encountering an obstacle.

Here's the code in question:

```
function moveForward(rover){
  console.log("moveForward was called");
  for(let k = 0; k < obstaclesList.length; k++){
  switch(rover.direction) {
    case "N": if(rover.y <= 0) { 
      console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
      } else if(rover.y === obstaclesList[k].j) {
      console.log("Obstacle was found!");
      return;
      } else {
      rover.y--;
      console.log("Rover moved up. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y);                           
  }
      break;
    case "W": if(rover.x <= 0) { 
      console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
      } else if(rover.x === obstaclesList[k].i) {
      console.log("Obstacle was found!");
      return;
      } else {
      rover.x--;
      console.log("Rover moved left. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y);
  }
      break;
    case "S": if(rover.y >= 10) { 
      console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
      } else if(rover.y === obstaclesList[k].j) {
      console.log("Obstacle was found!");
      return;
      } else {
      rover.y++;
      console.log("Rover moved down. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y);
  }
      break;
    case "E": if(rover.x >= 10) { 
      console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
      } else if(rover.x === obstaclesList[k].i) {
      console.log("Obstacle was found!");
      return;
      } else {
      rover.x++;
      console.log("Rover moved right. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y);         
  }
      break;
  }
  }
  roverMars.travelLog.push("x:" + rover.x + " y:" + rover.y);
}
```

I added a `return` in the `if-else` statement under `console.log("Obstacle was found!");`. However it didn't work, it kept going through the commands I input. I tried `break` in place of `return` but it didn't work either. Help?

Here's the rest of the code:

```js
// Rover Object Goes Here
// ======================
let roverMars = {
  direction: "N",
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  travelLog: ["x:0 y:0"]
};

let testBoard = [ 
  [null,"Rock2",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,"Bottle",null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,"Rock",null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"Statue",null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]
];
let obstaclesList = [];

for(let i = 0; i < testBoard.length; i++){
  for(let j = 0; j < testBoard[i].length; j++) {
    if(testBoard[i][j] !== null) {
      obstaclesList.push({i, j});
    }
  }
}

//console.log(obstaclesList[0].j);

// ======================
function turnLeft(rover){
  console.log("turnLeft was called!");
  switch(rover.direction) {
    case "N": rover.direction = "W";
      console.log("Rover is now facing " + rover.direction);
      break;
    case "W": rover.direction = "S";
      console.log("Rover is now facing " + rover.direction);
      break;
    case "S": rover.direction = "E";
      console.log("Rover is now facing " + rover.direction);
      break;
    case "E": rover.direction = "N";
      console.log("Rover is now facing " + rover.direction);
      break;
  }
}

function turnRight(rover){
  console.log("turnRight was called!");
  switch(rover.direction) {
    case "N": rover.direction = "E";
      console.log("Rover is now facing " + rover.direction);
      break;
    case "W": rover.direction = "N";
      console.log("Rover is now facing " + rover.direction);
      break;
    case "S": rover.direction = "W";
      console.log("Rover is now facing " + rover.direction);
      break;
    case "E": rover.direction = "S";
      console.log("Rover is now facing " + rover.direction);
      break;
  }
}

function moveForward(rover){
  console.log("moveForward was called");
  for(let k = 0; k < obstaclesList.length; k++){
  switch(rover.direction) {
    case "N": if(rover.y <= 0) { 
      console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
      } else if(rover.y === obstaclesList[k].j) {
      console.log("Obstacle was found!");
      return;
      } else {
      rover.y--;
      console.log("Rover moved up. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y);                           
  }
      break;
    case "W": if(rover.x <= 0) { 
      console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
      } else if(rover.x === obstaclesList[k].i) {
      console.log("Obstacle was found!");
      return;
      } else {
      rover.x--;
      console.log("Rover moved left. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y);
  }
      break;
    case "S": if(rover.y >= 10) { 
      console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
      } else if(rover.y === obstaclesList[k].j) {
      console.log("Obstacle was found!");
      return;
      } else {
      rover.y++;
      console.log("Rover moved down. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y);
  }
      break;
    case "E": if(rover.x >= 10) { 
      console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
      } else if(rover.x === obstaclesList[k].i) {
      console.log("Obstacle was found!");
      return;
      } else {
      rover.x++;
      console.log("Rover moved right. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y);         
  }
      break;
  }
  }
  roverMars.travelLog.push("x:" + rover.x + " y:" + rover.y);
}

function moveBackward(rover){
  console.log("moveBackward was called");
  
  switch(rover.direction) {
    case "N": if(rover.y >= 10) { 
      console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
      } else {
      rover.y++;
      console.log("Rover moved down. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y);                           
  }
      break;
    case "W": if(rover.x >= 10) { 
      console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
      } else {
      rover.x++;
      console.log("Rover moved right. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y);
  }
      break;
    case "S": if(rover.y <= 0) { 
      console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
      } else {
      rover.y--;
      console.log("Rover moved up. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y);
  }
      break;
    case "E": if(rover.x <= 0) { 
      console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
      } else {
      rover.x--;
      console.log("Rover moved left. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y);         
  }
      break;
  }
  roverMars.travelLog.push("x:" + rover.x + " y:" + rover.y);
}

function commandments(roverlist) {
  let passRegex = /[lrfb]/g;
  var passResult = roverlist.match(passRegex);
  for(let i = 0; i < passResult.length; i++) {
    switch(roverlist[i]) {
      case "l": turnLeft(roverMars);
        break;
      case "r": turnRight(roverMars);
        break;
      case "f": moveForward(roverMars);
        break;
      case "b": moveBackward(roverMars);
        break;
    }
  }
  //console.log("passResult: " + passResult);
}
commandments("rfffr");
//turnLeft(roverMars);
//turnRight(roverMars);
//moveForward(roverMars);
//console.log(roverMars.travelLog);
```

Which is at this link: https://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/PMaoYO

Comment: You're not supposed to move the rover oncee for every obstacle, right?

Comment: The instructions I read just said to stop the rover when it encounters the obstacles and say, "Obstacle found!". It didn't say to program it to move around it and continue the commands

Comment: If you want the loop to stop when a condition is met, then you should be using a while loop. it will break the loop when the condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

Name the loop and break from it

```js
function moveForward(rover) {
  console.log("moveForward was called");
  obstacleListLoop: for (let k = 0; k < obstaclesList.length; k++) {
    switch (rover.direction) {
      case "N":
        if (rover.y <= 0) {
          console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
        } else if (rover.y === obstaclesList[k].j) {
          console.log("Obstacle was found!");
          break obstacleListLoop;
        } else {
          rover.y--;
          console.log(
            "Rover moved up. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y
          );
        }
        break;
      case "W":
        if (rover.x <= 0) {
          console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
        } else if (rover.x === obstaclesList[k].i) {
          console.log("Obstacle was found!");
          break obstacleListLoop;
        } else {
          rover.x--;
          console.log(
            "Rover moved left. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y
          );
        }
        break;
      case "S":
        if (rover.y >= 10) {
          console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
        } else if (rover.y === obstaclesList[k].j) {
          console.log("Obstacle was found!");
          break obstacleListLoop;
        } else {
          rover.y++;
          console.log(
            "Rover moved down. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y
          );
        }
        break;
      case "E":
        if (rover.x >= 10) {
          console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
        } else if (rover.x === obstaclesList[k].i) {
          console.log("Obstacle was found!");
          break obstacleListLoop;
        } else {
          rover.x++;
          console.log(
            "Rover moved right. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y
          );
        }
        break;
    }
  }
  roverMars.travelLog.push("x:" + rover.x + " y:" + rover.y);
}
```

However, there's errors in your code (and there's some room for quality improvement). In `moveForward` you iterate over the obstacles and move once for each obstacle. Here's a version of `moveForward` that moves once and has better readability and closer is to idiomatic Javascript. Note that we no longer have the need to be able to break out of a nested loop. Also note that `Array.some` breaks the first time the method evaluates true for an element (i.e our first collision). I'd suggest you rewrite the other three `move` functions in the same style, or even better, consolidate them into one function. Good luck!

```js
const roverMars = {
  direction: "N",
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  travelLog: ["x:0 y:0"]
};

const testBoard = [
  [null, "Rock2", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
  [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
  [null, null, null, null, null, null, "Bottle", null, null, null],
  [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
  [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
  [null, null, null, "Rock", null, null, null, null, null, null],
  [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
  [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "Statue", null, null],
  [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
  [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
];

const obstacleList = testBoard.reduce(
  (acc, row, y) =>
    acc.concat(
      row
        .map((column, x) => (column === null ? null : x))
        .filter(x => x !== null)
        .map(x => ({ x, y }))
    ),
  []
);

console.log(`Obstacles: ${obstacleList.map(({ x, y }) => `x: ${x} y: ${y}`).join(', ')}`)

function moveForward(rover) {
  const crashedWithObstacle = ({ x: roverX, y: roverY }) => ({ x, y }) =>
    roverX === x && roverY === y;
  const newPosition = { x: rover.x, y: rover.y };

  let moveDirection;
  switch (rover.direction) {
    case "N":
      newPosition.y--;
      moveDirection = "up";
      break;
    case "E":
      newPosition.x++;
      moveDirection = "right";
      break;
    case "S":
      newPosition.y++;
      moveDirection = "down";
      break;
    case "W":
      newPosition.x--;
      moveDirection = "left";
      break;
  }

  if (
    newPosition.x < 0 ||
    newPosition.x > 9 ||
    newPosition.y < 0 ||
    newPosition.y > 9
  ) {
    console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
  } else if (obstacleList.some(crashedWithObstacle(newPosition))) {
    console.log("Obstacle was found!");
  } else {
    rover.x = newPosition.x;
    rover.y = newPosition.y;
    console.log(
      `Rover moved ${moveDirection}. The position is now ${rover.x}, ${rover.y}`
    );
  }
  roverMars.travelLog.push(`x:${rover.x} y:${rover.y}`);
}

moveForward(roverMars);
moveForward(roverMars);
```

Comment: Oh it works by stopping the loop when the rover encounters an obstacle! However, when I checked the console, it didn't show the `console.log("Obstacle was found!");` How do I fix that?

Comment: I updated my answer with a correctly implemented `moveForward`.

Comment: I tried to check out `obstacleList` in `console.log(obstaclesList);` but it didn't display any array?? How do I check it out?

Comment: That's because you misspelled `obstacleList`. I added a `console.log`